# Optimal parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, proof-explanation, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Using lagrangian, we could get optimal parameters of linear hard margin SVM which are $w^*$ and $b^*$. How can we approach this problem of proving that these parameters are indeed optimal?

Comment: duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3719189/linear-hard-margin-svm-proof-of-optimal-w-and-b

Comment: @LinAlg i dont think its duplicate that question is suggesting not to use Lagrange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard margin SVM is a convex problem. Both the objective function and constraints are convex. You can use KKT condition to prove that $w^*$ and $b^*$ are indeed optimal. Just check if the Lagrange multipliers are positive(usual notation).
**Notation:**
$$\
f(x)\leq0\\
g_i(x)\leq0 \ \forall i \in [n]\\
\mathcal L(x, \lambda_{[n]}) = f(x)+\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ig_i(x)
$$
**KKT Condition:** Suppose you want to verify if $x^*$ is the optimal,
If there exists $\lambda_i\geq0 \ \forall i \in [n]$ such that,
$$\
\nabla f(x^*) + \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\nabla g_i(x^*)=0
$$
Then, $x^*$ is indeed the optimal. There are some regulatory conditions but you need not worry about them as constraints for SVM are all linear.
Note that you can directly use the Lagrange multipliers obtained.

Comment: yeah, langrage multiplies in my case are indeed positive! what do you mean by usual notation?

Comment: @christopher I have added the notation in the answer.

Comment: can you also add details about the KKT condition and explain? I will mark the answer as correct!

Comment: It seems $\nabla g_i(w^*)$ is wrong. $\nabla g_i(w^*)$ should be $-y_i x_i$. Anyways the $w^*$ you have is not optimal. The optimal $w$ is $[-1, 1]^T$.